# I want to fetch movies data.

Tags: json, database, imdb

I want to fetch Indian movies database with all regional languages from internet.
How to fetch data from google search or from Wikipedia ? is it possible to fetch data as structured or have to set manually actors and directors to the movies ?
a details guide would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Well Wikipedia has an API you would be able to interact with, I'd guess you could also use something like IMDB, and more I'm probably not aware of. Python has a lot of packages that let you easily handle whatever you want to do with this data. I don't have the reputation to commment and ask, but if you can update your post with more information about what you're trying to do and how you want to do it there will be better answers for you.